# LLVM IR: get the return value of the callsite

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Here is a quick question on analyzing LLVM IR. So basically I am trying to fetch the return value of the LLVM IR function call statement, something like this:

```
%47  =   call i256 @test(i256 %46)
```

I want to get access `%47`.

And this is the code I have been using to access the parameter.

```
      else if (funcName.contains("test")) {
        Value *op = CI->getOperand(0);
        if (GetElementPtrInst *GEP = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(op))
          // get the first function parameter
          op = GEP->getPointerOperand();
      }
```

The very suprising finding is that I just cannot find something like "get return value" or so in the document: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html

Could anyone shed some lights here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get here? The actual return value that the function will return at run time as a constant? Obviously you won't be able to know this until run time (unless the call is constant-folded, in which case the `CallInst` no longer exists). Or an instruction that will evaluate to the return value? That's just the `CallInst` itself.

Comment: @sepp2k Thank you for the reply. So I want to get a `Value` instance of the variable `%47`.

Comment: That's the `CallInst`.

Comment: I have an use case similar to the one you asked, get the value of %47 and pass it as an argument to another function which accepts i32 type. The problem is if we just use CallInst, the parameter will look something like this call%47 i32 which wont be compatible with the new function which accepts i32 type. LLVM is SSA but scenarios like this is an interesting issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CI` (The `call` instruction) *is* its return value. It has a type that inherits `Value`.

If you want to do `1 + %47`, just as an example, you make an add like this: `Value * Add = BinaryOperation::Create(Instruction::Add, CI, ConstantInt::get(i256, 1), ...);` The add instruction, in turn, is its result, and `Add->getType() == i256` since it is the sum of two values that both have type `i256`.

Comment: Is there other way to get the return value of the function if i dont want to insert the instruction. All i want is the return value of the function

Comment: Since llvm is SSA, i thought i can simply pass the value to another instrumentation function but the type is not compatible. The new function param is of i32 type. If i pass as is it creates something like this call %i32 which is not compatible with i32 param type of the new function

Comment: The instruction *is* the value. If you don't insert the instruction, the value doesn't enter the program's universe. If you want to know the return value of a function, there has to be a call that function, and in SSA. the call instruction *is* the return value, see? Or is your real goal to reason at compile time about what the function might return, if called, but without calling it?

Comment: You can pass values, you need to cast. How to cast is up to you. Some languages sign-extend ints, so `true` becomes a 32-bit -1, others zero-extend so `true` becomes 1, for example. [CastInst::Create()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CastInst.html#a643fe5a9e7042f032dae78109c2b1e72) lets you do anything, so long as you decide what sort of cast is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As a different answer in case you need the string of the "return value" name, you can use `inst.getName()` or `inst.getNameOrAsOperand()` on the `Instruction` object, which is derived from the `Value` class.